# Bootstrap : vertical align and jumbotron height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched on internet for 4 hours but I don't find solutions.

I want to create a header for an HTML/CSS CV.
I wanted a header like this : http://hpics.li/ece0449

But I have a problem, I can't modify Jumbotron height in my css, without delete the vertical align contraint.

Also, I can't fix the height of the jumbotron to less than 50px

Please help me :)

HTML :

```
<body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 header_element">
                    <span class = "title_header">ADRESS</span> : XXX
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 header_element">
                    <span class = "title_header">PHONE</span> : XXX
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 header_element">
                    <span class = "title_header">EMAIL</span> : XXX
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.jumbotron{
background-color : #20B08F !important;
color : #FFFFFF;
}

.header_element{
background-color : #20B08F !important;
color : #FFFFFF;    
}

.header_element{
font-family: OpenSans_Light;
text-align : center;
}

.title_header{
font-family : OpenSans_Bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.jumbotron` doesn't have a set `height`, it gets its `height` from the `padding`. Decrease the following numbers to get a smaller jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
```

[**See example.**](http://www.bootply.com/GAXJ5NJ17X)